# Guía integrar api y servicio windows C# ( demonio ) .net core 3.1, que maneja mas de 600 peticion por el cliente

Tags: c#, api, peticiones

Actualmente, he construido una api que recibe un archivo zip de imagenes y guarda en una carpeta remota, después de eso realiza un registro en base de datos todo normal. Pero el requerimiento por parte de mi lider, es que este desarrollo pueda llegar a recibir esta misma petición, ( recibo de zip con imágenes ) por mas 600 dispositivos moviles.  Que son los usuario que actualmente haran uso de mi api.

Me dijeron que lo manejara con un aplicación de servicio de windows que corra en segundo plano,  para estar indicandole a los usuarios que fotos han sido guardadas correctamente en la carpeta remota, que fotos han marcado error y que fotos estan en proceso de ser guardadas.

Pero la verdad, no se como integrarlo el servicio de windows en una solución junto con la api, alguien sabe acerca de un proyecto real documentado en internet que me pueda guiar con respecto a este detalle.

Nunca he usado servicio windows de c#, pero si he leido. sobre su proposito mas en mi cabeza no se como manejarlo junto con lo que estoy desarrollando.

Yo solo estoy manejando, la parte del backend con la api

Si se como funciona el asincronismo en programacion, un midleware .. etc

[image: desarrollo con el que actualmente, cuento]

Comment: Podrias hacer que el servicio una vez concluido envie una notificacion push al celular con el mensaje que tu desees, o bien podrias hacer que la app refresque cada cierto tiempo y consulte la api sobre el estado de los archivos.

Comment: muchas gracias, estuve investigando y me pasaron una idea similar. pues el servicio de windows hara la chamba que hace actualmente el api ... buscar las imagenes descomprimidas y  hara registros en base de datos. mas realizar operaciones sobre 2 tablas en base de datos para mandar estados de esas operaciones ( buscar las imagenes descomprimidas, registros en base de datos, pendiente de guardar , procesado etc ).

Comment: La api , solo recibira el zip y lo guardara en una ubicacion, registrandola tambien y estara consultando estados, cada que el cliente lo decida.